# SVG dashed line animation does not work in Chrome

Tags: css, animation, svg

In my animation is used `CSS`, `SVG` and `JS`.

I create some paths. User have possibility to choose path, what he want to see. After button click, the selected path start drawing. My animation works in `Mozzilla` and `Edge`, but it does not work in `Chrome`. My code looks like:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    .opcjaApath{
      -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -o-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
    }

    .opcjaBpath{
      -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -o-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    </style>
```

```
<html>
      <button id="A"> Option A </button> 
      <button id="B"> Option B </button> 

      <svg width="400" height="300">

        <g id="optionA">
          <path class="opcjaApath" d="M50,30 250,30 250,54 50,54 50,78 250,78 250,102 50,102 50,126 250,126 250,150 50,150 50,174 250,174 250,198 50,198 50,222 250,222 250,246 50,246 50,270 250,270" stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
        </g>
        <g id="optionB">

          <path class="opcjaBpath" d="M150,150 150,126 170,126 170,174 130,174 130,102 190,102 190,198 110,198 110,78 210,78 210,222 90,222 90,54 230,54 230,246 70,246 70,30 250,30 250,270 50,270 50,30" stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
        </g>
      </svg>

    </html>
```

```
    <script>
    $("#optionA").hide();
    $("#optionB").hide();


    $('#A').click(function(){
      hidebutton() 
      $("#optionA").show();
      $("#optionB").hide();
      setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
    });

    $('#B').click(function(){
      hidebutton() 
      $("#optionB").show();
      $("#optionA").hide();
      setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
    });

    function showbutton() {
      $("#A").show();
      $("#B").show();
    }

    function hidebutton() {
      $("#A").hide();
      $("#B").hide();
    }
    <script>
```

I do not know, why it is not working in `Chrome`... Maybe do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference in behaviour seems to be because Chrome is starting the animations as soon as the page loads.  Whereas Firefox and Edge are only triggering the animations once the SVGs become visible.

I don't know which behaviour is correct.

But the solution to this problem is to not add those classes to the `<path>` elements until you want them to start playing.

1. Remove the `class="obcjaApath"` attributes from the paths
2. Change your click handlers so that they add the classes back when the SVG is made visible:

   ```
   $('#A').click(function(){
     hidebutton() 
     $("#optionA").show();
     $("#optionA").addClass("opcjaApath");
     $("#optionB").hide();
     $("#optionB").removeClass("opcjaBpath");
     setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
   });
   ```

Full demo:

```js
$("#optionA").hide();
$("#optionB").hide();


$('#A').click(function(){
  hidebutton() 
  $("#optionA").show();
  $("#optionA").addClass("opcjaApath");
  $("#optionB").hide();
  $("#optionB").removeClass("opcjaBpath");
  setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
});

$('#B').click(function(){
  hidebutton() 
  $("#optionB").show();
  $("#optionB").addClass("opcjaBpath");
  $("#optionA").hide();
  $("#optionA").removeClass("opcjaApath");
  setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
});

function showbutton() {
  $("#A").show();
  $("#B").show();
}

function hidebutton() {
  $("#A").hide();
  $("#B").hide();
}
```

```css
.opcjaApath{
      -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -o-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
    }

    .opcjaBpath{
      -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      stroke-dasharray: 2684;
      stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        -o-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes dash1 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="A"> Option A </button> 
<button id="B"> Option B </button> 

<svg width="400" height="300">

  <g id="optionA">
    <path d="M50,30 250,30 250,54 50,54 50,78 250,78 250,102 50,102 50,126 250,126 250,150 50,150 50,174 250,174 250,198 50,198 50,222 250,222 250,246 50,246 50,270 250,270" stroke="red"
          stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
  </g>
  <g id="optionB">

    <path d="M150,150 150,126 170,126 170,174 130,174 130,102 190,102 190,198 110,198 110,78 210,78 210,222 90,222 90,54 230,54 230,246 70,246 70,30 250,30 250,270 50,270 50,30" stroke="red"
          stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I wanted that the second behaviour was happened. This solution is very good. I see the difference and I can correct my project. Thanks a lot for you time and advice!

Answer (score -1):

Your code format is wrong. check below.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .opcjaApath {
            -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
            -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -o-stroke-dasharray: 2684;
            -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            stroke-dasharray: 2684;
            stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
        }

        .opcjaBpath {
            -webkit-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -o-animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation: dash1 10s linear forwards;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            stroke-dasharray: 2684;
            stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes dash1 {
            0% {
                -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes dash1 {
            0% {
                -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            }

            100% {
                -moz-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }

        @-o-keyframes dash1 {
            0% {
                -o-stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            }

            100% {
                -o-stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }

        @keyframes dash1 {
            0% {
                stroke-dashoffset: 2684;
            }

            100% {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <button id="A"> Option A </button>
        <button id="B"> Option B </button>

        <svg width="400" height="300">

            <g id="optionA">
                <path class="opcjaApath"
                    d="M50,30 250,30 250,54 50,54 50,78 250,78 250,102 50,102 50,126 250,126 250,150 50,150 50,174 250,174 250,198 50,198 50,222 250,222 250,246 50,246 50,270 250,270"
                    stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
            </g>
            <g id="optionB">

                <path class="opcjaBpath"
                    d="M150,150 150,126 170,126 170,174 130,174 130,102 190,102 190,198 110,198 110,78 210,78 210,222 90,222 90,54 230,54 230,246 70,246 70,30 250,30 250,270 50,270 50,30"
                    stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
            </g>
        </svg>

    </center>


    <script>
        $("#optionA").hide();
        $("#optionB").hide();


        $('#A').click(function () {
            hidebutton()
            $("#optionA").show();
            $("#optionB").hide();
            setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
        });

        $('#B').click(function () {
            hidebutton()
            $("#optionB").show();
            $("#optionA").hide();
            setTimeout(showbutton, 10000);
        });

        function showbutton() {
            $("#A").show();
            $("#B").show();
        }

        function hidebutton() {
            $("#A").hide();
            $("#B").hide();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the path start drawing after button click and I want to see dashed line. It is work properly in  Mozilla and Edge, but it does not work in Chrome. After button click in chrome, I see path, not dashed line...

Comment: My code, what I wrote, was the same as you, but I wrong copy to stackoverflow from codepen project. This solution does not work in Chrome, so you post does not solved my problem.